# Youtube API LiveBroadcast - One Stream ID - different StreamName

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I use Youtube API to insert Leave Broadcast (from example). I have only one Live Broadcast (not Stream NOW).

```
$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',$broadcastInsert, array());
```

After it:

1) I use Youtube API to get StreamName (LiveStream list).

```
$streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->listLiveStreams('id,snippet,cdn,status', array(
        'mine' => 'true',
    ));

Item[id] == 5QnRV-iujHFlNeFHdlaagA1472664846676130

Item[cdn][ingestionInfo][streamName] ==  "4v9y-cet5-jd9x-1af4"
```

2) I use https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list to get StreamName ("Try it!" section).

```
"id": "5QnRV-iujHFlNeFHdlaagA1472664846676130",
   "cdn": {
     "streamName": "kwhz-mu2v-ed38-af7s",
```

3) I go to https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events to see "Ingestion Settings" for this Leave Broadcast

I see Stream Name: fr94-bswu-b1tq-376s

Why it happen? One broadcast, same stream id, but different Stream Name. I am confused.

I would be grateful for any idea.
Thanks, Oleg.

Comment: Oleg: Did you ever discover what was wrong? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't receive answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway. From what I checked, the keys are different if creating the stream from API and from the panel - but when creating from API both work. If creating from panel, the API one doesn't.